# How to collect nested data in Vue.js without duplicates?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vue-component

A second question about my project *"Avatar database"*. I want to collect all tags from all avatars into one array. Of course the list should not contain duplicates.

For example, I have 3 avatars with the tag "red" and in the array "allTags" - "red" is displayed only once.

#### Data structure

```js
data() {
  return {
    avatars: [
      {
        name: "Butterfly Blue",
        tags: ["animal", "butterfly", "blue"]
      },
      {
        name: "Butterfly Green",
        tags: ["animal", "butterfly", "green"]
      },
      {
        name: "Deer Shining",
        tags: ["animal", "deer"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get those tags using a `computed` property:

```js
allTags() {
  var result = [];
  for (var avatar in this.avatars) {
    for (var tag in avatar.tags) {
      if (!tag in result) {
        result += tag
      }
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

**But...** The only output I can see is: `[]` - an empty array.

I want the `computed` property `allTags` to return an array (`[]`) of all tags from all avatars.

Using the example data above `{{ allTags }}` should be:

```js
[ "animal", "butterfly", "blue", "green", "deer" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `!result.includes(tag)` instead of `!tag in result`, and `result.push(tag)` instead of `result += tag`:

```
allTags() {
  var result = [];
  for (let avatar of this.avatars) {
    for (let tag of avatar.tags) {
      if (!result.includes(tag)) {
        result.push(tag)
      }
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

Also, I have replaced the use of `for..in` with `for..of`, this is the recommended construct.

See demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      avatars: [{
          name: "Butterfly Blue",
          tags: ["animal", "butterfly", "blue"]
        },
        {
          name: "Butterfly Green",
          tags: ["animal", "butterfly", "green"]
        },
        {
          name: "Deer Shining",
          tags: ["animal", "deer"]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    allTags() {
      var result = [];
      for (let avatar of this.avatars) {
        for (let tag of avatar.tags) {
          if (!result.includes(tag)) {
            result.push(tag)
          }
        }
      }
      return result
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h4>Avatars:</h4>
  <p>{{ avatars }}</p>
  
  <hr>
  <h4>allTags:</h4>
  <p>{{ allTags }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Very thank you! One thing... Why `for..of` instead of `for..in`?